# Confirmation once a user has submitted a list form

Tags: list, form, modal-dialog

We have quite a few lists on our sites where users fill out forms to add items to a list. One thing that has always bugged me (and my users) is once they fill out the form the dialog just goes away.

No thank you, No your form was submitted successfully, no confirmation.

How can I get a confirmation message to my users once they have submitted the form. Or even redirect them to another page?

Thanks

Comment: What type of form that you develop?

Answer (score 1):

You can utilize the`PresaveAction` function. This will let you run code just before saving a list item. See: http://www.ilikesharepoint.de/2014/06/sharepoint-presaveaction-helps-for-actions-before-saving-an-item.